# An efficient way to read from a text file into a database table

Tags: c#, delphi, io, textreader

I have a log file. The file is structured. Each line is delimeted by commas so that it looks like a table. I have to read from this file and transport the content to a database table. I want to treat the first 9 commas as delimeters and the rest ones as just a content of the tenth column. So, there can be more than 9 commas in a line but the tenth and the next ones shoudn't be taken as a delimeter. I actually know how to do it by iterating through the characters and checking occurance of commas. But I don't want it be inefficient. maybe there's a better way? What would be the most accurate way to accomplish this? Either C# or Delphi is OK. For Oracle I'll probably use Oracle but SQL Server is also an option.

Comment: Strange that this got a downvote.. +1 to compensate :)

Comment: Thank you @Wouter van Nifterick. I also sometimes find it hard to understand the reason behind downvoting.

Comment: In order to get an accurate answer you need to specify details, I think that's the reason for the downvote. Which database are you using?, Many databases can read CSV data directly into the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`String.Split(char[],int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) method overload achieves what you require. For example:

```
string line = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n";
string[] fields = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 10);
```

The `fields` array will contain ten elements. The first nine elements correspond the first nine substrings of `line` that were delimited by `','` characters, whilst the last element would correspond to the remaining substring (following the ninth `','` occurrence).

From MSDN (with `count` being the second argument passed to the `Split(char[], int)` method):

> If there are more than `count` substrings in this instance, the first `count` minus 1 substrings are returned in the first `count` minus 1 elements of the return value, and the remaining characters in this instance are returned in the last element of the return value.

Thus, executing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("fields[{0}]: \"{1}\"", i, fields[i]));
```

would output:

```
fields[0]: "a"
fields[1]: "b"
fields[2]: "c"
fields[3]: "d"
fields[4]: "e"
fields[5]: "f"
fields[6]: "g"
fields[7]: "h"
fields[8]: "i"
fields[9]: "j,k,l,m,n"
```

Comment: Thank you body. I did exactly as you said. I think this is the best thing that can do my job.

Comment: Does anyone know if there a similar method in Delphi other than using a StringList and its delimiter property?

Comment: I would suggest that you open a new question with your query, and label it with the `Delphi` tag. Posting on a comment of an answered question is hardly likely to get you any attention.

Answer (score 3):

Some databases have ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) facilities that allows for importing external data very quickly and efficiently once set up. How flexible they are depends on the database - you didn't say which is.
To identify your columns in Delphi I'd use regular expressions, anyway they do exactly what you would do - iterate the string and match characters, just a good regex library can be fast (and flexible).
What you should avoid is read one character per file read. Read n lines into a memory buffer and process them there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [FileHelpers Library](http://www.filehelpers.com/) and its DatabaseStorage class.